# R, igraph, Big Data: Calculating Vertex to Vertex Shortest Distance with Very Large Network

Tags: r, bigdata, igraph

I have a very large network based on 100K unique vertices and 500M edges (note: edges are all distance 1 (binary) and undirected).

I need to create a 100K by 100K matrix of the shortest distances between each vertex pair.

I am using `igraph` and the `distances()` command, which creates exactly what I want with something like this:

```
distance_mat <- distances(network, v=V(network), to=V(network), weights=NA)
```

However, it gets very slow with a network of this magnitude - current estimates have my code needing > 10 days to complete on a 2.5 GHz i7 Mac with 16GB of RAM.

Has anyone optimized a routine to do something like this with such a large network or have ideas on how to speed this up?

Here is some sample code to build a large (but not full size) network to practice on if it helps:

```
require(igraph)

n_id <- 100000
n_connect <- 100000000
id1 <- sample(1:n_id,n_connect,replace=T)
id2 <- sample(1:n_id,n_connect,replace=T)
nbr <- rep(1,n_connect)
idall <- unique(c(id1,id2))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(id1,id2,nbr))

network <- graph_from_data_frame(d=df, vertices=idall, directed=F)

Sys.time()
dist_df <- distances(network, v=V(network)[1:1000], to=V(network)[1:1000], weights=NA)
Sys.time()
```

Comment: Maybe you'd need heavier tooling like Neo4J or Spark GraphX (I can't advise which, having used none).

Comment: 100K x 100K = 10G numbers. Since each distance will be an 8-byte number,  your matrix will require 80GB Just for the matrix. Your 16GB machine will be swapping like crazy.

Comment: BTW,   how long did it take to run the 1Kx1K chunk in your example code?

Comment: @G5W Agreed on the swapping. I’ve been exploring ways of looping through subsets of the vertices to minimize this issue. In terms of current speed, the real data with a 1K x 1K run takes about 10 mins. Using this example code is only about a minute since the number of edges and total indices is smaller.

Comment: One approach I tried is to “fill in the diagonal” one row at a time, using progressively smaller subsets in the “to” entry, but at its fastest this takes about 7 seconds per row = 7 x 100K seconds...

Comment: If you get any significant reduction from this,  please come back and post an answer to your own question. It could be useful to others.

Comment: No dice on the row-by-row for loop. Even when I do a `distances()` or `shortest.paths()` function matching 1 vertex to 1 other vertex, the command takes about 5-8 seconds (i.e. `shortest.paths(network,v=V(network)[1],to=V(network)[2],weights=NA)`), which predicts a minimum of a 500K-800K second total run time